# C# / EmguCv Argument Out of Range exception when creating images from byte[]

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I try to use the MatchTemplate on edgeimages to find teached objects in an image. As image source i use a kinect2. I first teach an edge image and search the teached template in later captured image. Calculating the edge images with canny works very good. I save the edges as byte[] with

```
byte[] bytes = cannyFrame.GetData();
```

Later I try to create Image with the given data. Unfortunately sometimes creating the image runs in a ArgumentOutOfRange-Exception and claims that the array is to big. Sometimes the exception occurs and sometimes it doesn't occure. The exception can occur creating the current image and also when I'm creating the teached image (see comments in my code). Can anybody tell me, why this exception occurs?

```
        Bitmap bmp; 

        //bmp is filled with the image from the kinect

        int width;
        int height;
        byte[] currentEdges = EdgeDetector.CalculateEdges(bmp, referenceImage.BorderOne, referenceImage.BorderTwo, out width, out height);
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ref width: {0}, height: {1}, byte[]length: {2}", referenceImage.Width_px, referenceImage.Height_px, referenceImage.Edges.Length);                
            //Here happens the exception sometimes: 
            Image<Gray, byte> templateImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(referenceImage.Width_px, referenceImage.Height_px);
            templateImage.Bytes = referenceImage.Edges;
            Console.WriteLine("current image width: {0}, height: {1}, byte[]length: {2}", width, height, currentEdges.Length);

            //Here happens the exception sometimes: 
            Image<Gray, byte> searchImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(width, height);
            searchImage.Bytes = currentEdges;
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Image<Gray, float> imgMatch = searchImage.MatchTemplate(templateImage, TemplateMatchingType.CcoeffNormed);
            }
        catch (Exception)
        {                
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }


    internal class EdgeDetector
    {
        internal static byte[] CalculateEdges(Bitmap bmp, int borderOne, int borderTwo, out int width, out int height)
        {
            try
            {
                Image<Bgr, byte> img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bmp);

                Mat smallGrayFrame = new Mat();
                Mat smoothedGrayFrame = new Mat();
                Mat cannyFrame = new Mat();

                CvInvoke.PyrDown(img, smallGrayFrame);

                CvInvoke.PyrUp(smallGrayFrame, smoothedGrayFrame);

                CvInvoke.Canny(smoothedGrayFrame, cannyFrame, borderOne, borderTwo);

                byte[] bytes = cannyFrame.GetData();

                width = cannyFrame.Width;
                height = cannyFrame.Height;

                return bytes;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                width = 0;
                height = 0;
                return null;
            }
        }
```

an example output:
ref width: 46, height: 44, byte[]length: 2024
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Requested range extends past the end of the
array.
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.CopyToNative(Object source, Int32 s
tartIndex, IntPtr destination, Int32 length)
   at Emgu.CV.CvArray`1.set_Bytes(Byte[] value)
   at AlgorithmsHelper.SearchEdgeImage(AssistentEdgeImageOpenCv referenceImage, Image currentImage)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't have an idea why the exception occurs, but I've found a solution as walkaround. Like in http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images suggested i create a Mat, fill it with the bytes and create an image from the Mat witch works fine.

```
            Mat currentMat;
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(currentEdges))
            {
                byte[] rawData = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
                memoryStream.Read(rawData, 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);

                GCHandle rawDataHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(rawData, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                IntPtr address = rawDataHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();

                currentMat = new Mat(new System.Drawing.Size(width, height), DepthType.Cv8U, 1, address, width);
                rawDataHandle.Free();
            }
            Image<Gray, byte> currentImage = currentMat.ToImage<Gray, byte>();

            Mat templateMat;
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(referenceImage.Edges))
            {
                byte[] rawData = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
                memoryStream.Read(rawData, 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);

                GCHandle rawDataHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(rawData, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                IntPtr address = rawDataHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();

                templateMat = new Mat(new System.Drawing.Size(referenceImage.Width_px, referenceImage.Height_px), DepthType.Cv8U, 1, address, referenceImage.Width_px);
                rawDataHandle.Free();
            }
            Image<Gray, byte> templateImage = templateMat.ToImage<Gray, byte>();

            Image<Gray, float> imgMatch = currentImage.MatchTemplate(templateImage, TemplateMatchingType.CcoeffNormed);
```